# Design Pattern : .NET C# , I have to check 100+ compliance

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern, method-chaining

Design Pattern : .NET , I have to check 100+ compliance.
For each compliance I have to create a separate class for it.
Which is the best solution/Design pattern to build application which checks all compliance with one go, connecting each compliance to each other ?

As its not yet designed, so I am asking for input for a better designing.
Requirements : A compliance check for all the banks.
Each bank have different rule set before giving a loan approval and few rule set are based on government norms.
Scenario : 
1. Common Ruleset for Federal government.
2. Each states have their own rule set.
3. Each bank have their own rule set.

In Project Classname would be like

```
Class BankOfAmerica
{
//all rules
}

Class Bank2
{
//all rules
}
Class State1
{
//all rules
}
Class State2
{
//all rules
}
Class Country
{
//all rules
}
```

Now for a single user , I want to check eligibility for a loan against more than one bank including different states and a country.

Comment: too general question - please show how do you currently resolve 100+ compliance task ?

Comment: What is a "compliance"? Please show us your code.

Comment: Compliance is set of rules that must have to fulfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Composite pattern is the answer. You should extract the compliance interface from your 100+ compliancies:

```
public interface ICompliance 
{
    bool IsCompliant {get;}
}
```

and implement composite compliance:

```
public class ConfjunctionCompositeCompliance 
{
    IList<ICompliance> compliancies = new List<ICompliance>();

    public Add(ICompliance compl) {...}

    public bool IsCompliant 
    {
         get { return compliancies.Aggregate(true, (c, a) => c &= a.IsCompliant); }
    }
 }
```

(of course you can optimize checking for conjunction and disjunction boolean checks)